# SO composer require rebing/graphql-laravel fails

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse, graphql-playground

I have the following problem trying to install **rebing/graphql-laravel** via *composer*:

```sh
$ composer require rebing/graphql-laravel
Using version ^2.1 for rebing/graphql-laravel
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for rebing/graphql-laravel ^2.1 -> satisfiable by rebing/graphql-laravel[2.1.0, 2.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.6, 0.13.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[0.13.x-dev, v0.12.6].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[0.13.x-dev, v0.12.6].
    - Conclusion: install webonyx/graphql-php 0.13.x-dev
    - Installation request for webonyx/graphql-php 0.12.6 -> satisfiable by webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this? I need this package to make this query resolver:

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;
use App\Video;


class Premieres extends Query {

    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Premieres query'
    ];

    public function type(): Type {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('videos'));
    }

    public function args(): array {
        return [];
    }

    public function resolve($root, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo, Closure $getSelectFields) {
        return Video::where('shownOnPremieres', 1);
    }
}
```

I don't know that else to try to solve this. I need to make a query resolver to do some specific queries. Thanks!

After trying one of the proposed solutions:

```sh
$ composer update webonyx/graphql-php rebing/graphql-laravel
Package "rebing/graphql-laravel" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: nuwave/lighthouse
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-cors
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Re-run the installation command:

```sh
$ composer require rebing/graphql-laravel -v

Using version ^2.1 for rebing/graphql-laravel
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Dependency resolution completed in 0.103 seconds
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for rebing/graphql-laravel ^2.1 -> satisfiable by rebing/graphql-laravel[2.1.0, 2.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.6, 0.13.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[0.13.x-dev, v0.12.6].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[0.13.x-dev, v0.12.6].
    - Conclusion: install webonyx/graphql-php 0.13.x-dev
    - Installation request for webonyx/graphql-php 0.12.6 -> satisfiable by webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

And it failed!

Comment: Try running `composer` with the [`-v` flag](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `rebing/graphql-laravel` require `webonyx/graphql-php` on version more than [`0.13`](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel/blob/2.0.1/composer.json#L39).

It seems also that `webonyx/graphql-php` is already required in your composer file so you need to update the sub-dependency  with

`composer update webonyx/graphql-php rebing/graphql-laravel`

Comment: Posted it in the article.

Comment: If you edit directly your `composer.json` by adding `rebing/graphql-laravel: ^2.1` then re-run `composer update webonyx/graphql-php rebing/graphql-laravel` does it give better result ?

Comment: I've solved it:

`"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^5.8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground": "^1.1.0",
        "nuwave/lighthouse": "^4.4.2",
        "spatie/laravel-cors": "^1.6",
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.13.8",
        "rebing/graphql-laravel": "2.1.1" 
    },`

But now I'm having this other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404470/in-router-php-line-366-argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-routing-routergroup