# In Router.php line 366: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type array,

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8, laravel-lighthouse, graphql-php

I have update **Laravel** from `v5.7` to `v5.8` and now my application doesn't run.

I updated it because of this issue: [composer require rebing/graphql-laravel fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369552/composer-require-rebing-graphql-laravel-fails)

I solved the packages incompatibility but now Laravel crashes:

```sh
$ php artisan serve

In Router.php line 366:

  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/masvino/Server-bak/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades  
  /Facade.php on line 239
```

I suspect that the Laravel's team changed the firm of this method:

**Illuminate\Routing\Router.php**

```php
    /**
     * Create a route group with shared attributes.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  \Closure|string  $routes
     * @return void
     */
    public function group(array $attributes, $routes) // line 366
    {
        $this->updateGroupStack($attributes);

        // Once we have updated the group stack, we'll load the provided routes and
        // merge in the group's attributes when the routes are created. After we
        // have created the routes, we will pop the attributes off the stack.
        $this->loadRoutes($routes);

        array_pop($this->groupStack);
    }
```

This is the current content of my **composer.json** file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^5.8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground": "^1.1.0",
        "nuwave/lighthouse": "^4.4.2",
        "spatie/laravel-cors": "^1.6",
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.13.8",
        "rebing/graphql-laravel": "2.1.1" 
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [],
            "providers": [
                "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQLServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "GraphQL": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Facades\\GraphQL"
            }
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I think the problem could be in this file:
**app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

Don't know which is the correct format now for `group()` method. Can anybody help me figure this out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

As the error message suggests, the problem is solved by adding an empty array into the web.php file.

```
Route::group([], function () {
   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

And I am using Laravel v7.

Comment: This is helpful in Laravel 8. Thank you

Comment: It helped in L8

Comment: I did this and after that, for laravel 8 i commented out all routes, api and web, after that i read the exact line where the error is thrown via laravel web console

Answer (score 0):

You can just use in your routes/web.php

```
Route::group( ['prefix' => 'backend','middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function() {}
```

Comment: Can you display your routes here?

Answer (score 0):

**same problem but i fixed it !**

run composer update and then run php artisan route:clear and
then
use attributes before using route group function exemple:

```
Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        // Route assigned name 'admin.dashboard'...
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all the cache files from this directory (laravel\bootstrap\cache)
2. run artisan command "php artisan optimize"